# Rails - Save item from index and write it to a new Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, model

I have a list of tweets on my index (Twit model, twits controller) with a checkbox aside. What I'd like to do is to save checked tweets to an other model (Repost model, reposts controller).

The Repost model will have the same attribute as the Twit one. I just want to select specific tweets from my index View and save them to the Repost model.

Here is my View:

```
<%= form_tag reposts_path do %>
<ul>
  <% @twits.each do |twit| %>
    <li>
      <%= twit.like %> likes
      <%= check_box_tag "repost_twit_#{twit.id}"  %> -
      <%= link_to twit_path(twit) do %>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
      <% end %> -
      <%= link_to twit_path(twit), method: :delete do %>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<%= submit_tag "Add to your Repost library", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

I have the logic as I succeed doing it within my Rails console, but I can't do it within the app... It will be like this `Repost.create(like:Twit.first.like)`

I am obviously missing something. Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you submit this form, what are the request params shown in logs.

Comment: Hi @Bijendra, I have this message => No template found for RepostsController#create, rendering head :no_content I understand that my View new/create is missing but I want to do this from my TwitController#index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple option available to solve the issue you have. Firstly there is no clarity you want to handle this with ajax call or html call. I have assumed it's html call with full page reload every time data is sent.

Let data be loaded as currently, except it should submit to the same action of reports say update. So now,

```
    twits_controller.rb
      def index
        @twits = Twit.all
      end

      def update
      end
```

In update action, look for the checkbox attribute from the request params and if found, on a conditional basis create Repost entries with data from Twit model.

```
      Repost.create(:name: "This is name", content: "content")
```

After save, render index template(create.html.erb) and create a instance variable like

```
      @twits = Twit.all
```

This will keep fetching the data as desired. Also, if you want to preserve the checkbox values, make sure to have a **attribute in twits table** to save this. On every page reload, the checkboxes should change as per db value. This will not give the template missing error currently.

If you want to go with ajax call then on the twits index page make the form submit as ajax(remote: true ) as suggested in another answer. On submit, use the attribute value to identify the checkbox and save in Repost model.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time, you point me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create html then go with ajax.

```
<%= form_tag reposts_path, remote: true do %>
```

and in your `RepostsController#create` add a respond_to :js

```
def create
  Repost.create(params[:repost])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

And create a `app/views/reposts/create.js.erb`

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciate that!